# Screenshot doesn't appear at Photos app (iOS obj-c)

Tags: ios, objective-c, screenshot

I'm trying to save screenshot of my app using next code:

```
UIView* view = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] subviews] lastObject];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.bounds.size);
[view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
NSData * data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

NSURL* documentsDirectory = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
NSString* filename = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: @"screenshot.png"];
NSString* path =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",[documentsDirectory path], filename];

BOOL saved = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:path contents:data attributes:nil];
NSLog(saved ? @"Saved" : @"Not saved");
```

It logs `Saved`, but image doesn't appear in Photos app.

`documentsDirectory`: `/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/003D7989-D88E-48FF-A3C5-86A340C6F077/Documents`

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks for response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code to save an Image in Photo app

```
NSData * data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(compressedPNGImage,
                               self,
                               @selector(thisImage:hasBeenSavedInPhotoAlbumWithError:usingContextInfo:),
                               NULL);
```

then you should implement the above selector as below

```
- (void)thisImage:(UIImage *)image hasBeenSavedInPhotoAlbumWithError:(NSError *)error usingContextInfo:(void*)ctxInfo
{
    if (error)
    {
        // not saved
    }
    else
    {
        // saved
    }
}
```

finally, be sure to add "Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description" key in Info target settings

Comment: hmm, it's now saving to Photos, but it is purely white image

Comment: well, maybe the "image" is white :) I'll update source code ;)

Comment: I think you should simply get current viewController's view instead of "UIView* view = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] subviews] lastObject];"